# How to remove Outlook add in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, outlook, officedev

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community to create an Outlook add in via the Office Developer Tools

When I run debug Visual Studio, it opens Outlook and I can see my plug in.

When I close Outook and Visual Studio, and restart Outlook, I can **still** see the plug in.

How do I remove it so it only shows when I load Outlook via Visual Studio?

The reason for this is, I'm about to create the installer. Based upon this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx#Obtain I have to create registry entries. I'd like to have the guarantee that the only reason the plug in exists in Outlook is due to the installation of the app, not because it already existed previously due to my debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove your plugin when you go to **Developer Tools** and click on button **COM Add-Ins**. This opens a dialog where you're able to remove your plugin. Otherwise it will stay on in Outlook.

Comment: For that, one needs to activate the ribbon item, then it can be accessed. Worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating new VM with clean MS Office installation so you can test the installer in more realistic scenario.

This gives you ability to revert VM to previous state in case the installer misbehaves during development.

I would definitely not recommend testing installer on development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, according to a guide by Microsoft is to click on `Clean Solution` in the `Build` menu in Visual Studio (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#clean-up-the-project)